# create two child processes managed by parent

Tags: c, linux, fork

i have to write program, which will create two child processes
These processes would write something in the file, but both processes are managed by the parent(which process will write)
i am not asking you guys for direct solutions, but i need some hints, to know where to start from. 
I guess i have to create two forks at start and then manage it through case, or something like that
thanks

Comment: You might get some more help if you elaborate on what you mean by "managed by the parent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the basic `fork()` usage pattern, which looks like so:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
  // child process code starts here
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
   // parent process code continues here
}
```

Sounds like you are going to need two `fork()`s, which means you need to use this pattern nested. That's the basic usage, all the rest is up to your application.